# Access from my main form class into specific class method

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my main form class and inside i have `Stop button click event`:

```
public partial class MainWin : Form
{
    private Job job = new...

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       job.state = true;
    }
}
```

When my stop button clicked i change my job class member from false to true and what i want to do is when this variable changed to true  i want to access to specific method inside job class and do something.

```
public class Job
{
    public bool state { get; set; }

    private void processFile() // i want access to this method in order to change other class state
    {
       // do work
    }
}
```

how can i do it ?

Comment: You cannot access a private method outside of a class. Are you allowed to change the method's access specifier to internal/public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really hard to tell what you exactly mean, but one way to invoke a method when the property is set would be to expand the auto property out and do exactly that.

```
public class Job
{
    private bool state;
    public bool State
    {
       get { return this.state; }
       set
       {
          this.state = value;
          processFile();
       } 

    private void processFile()
    {
       // do work
    }
}
```

However, just guessing and seeing this little bit of code, you might want to redesign how you're doing things.

Comment: If you set the State to `false`, it will process again.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `Job` class like this:

```
public class Job
{
    private bool _isRunning = false;
    public bool IsRunning { get { return _isRunning; } }

    public void StartProcessing()
    {
        if (_isRunning)
        {   
            // TODO: warn?      
            return;
        }
        ProcessFile();
    }

    public void StopProcessing()
    {
        if (!_isRunning)
        {   
            // TODO: warn?
            return;
        }
        // TODO: stop processing
    }

    private void ProcessFile()
    {
        _isRunning = true;

        // do your thing

        _isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Then consume it like this:

```
public partial class MainWin : For
{
    private Job _job = new Job();

    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!_job.IsRunning)
        {
            _job.StartProcessing();
        }
    }

    private void StopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(_job.IsRunning)
        {           
            _job.StopProcessing();
        }
    }
}
```

Thread safety left out as exercise.

Answer (score 0):

If really don't want to expose you private method, you can do something like this:

```
public class Job
{
    private bool state;

    public bool State
    {
        get
        {
            return state;
        }
        set
        {
            if (state != value)
            {
                state = value;
                OnStateChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnStateChanged()
    {
        if (state) // or you could use enum for state
            Run();
        else
            Stop();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        // run
    }

    private void Stop()
    {
        // stop
    }
}
```

But you should really consider creating public `Job.Run` method and leaving `Job.State` readonly. If you want the object to perform some operations, the methods will be more suitable for this.